# Writing a tuple that converts polar coordinates to x and y

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a script that takes Polar coordinates from a user (r, theta) and converts them to Cartesian coordinates (x, y) using tuples. I am new to programming in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import math
def get_input():
    rstring = input('\n' 'Please enter r >> ')
    r = float(rstring)
    thetastring = input('\n' 'Please enter THETA >> ')
    theta = float(thetastring)
    pcoordinates = (r, theta)
    return pcoordinates
    x = r * math.cos(theta)
    y = r * math.sin(theta)
    return x, y
    print('The Cartesian coordinates for',r,'and',theta,'are', x, 'and', y)
get_input()
```

A user is supposed to be able to input (r, theta) and get (x, y) in return. Instead I am just getting "Process finished with exit code 0" after entering (r, theta)

x = r * math.cos(theta) and y = r * math.sin(theta) appear to be unreachable, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: You never call the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function finishes and returns when a `return` line is encountered. So your `get_input` function finishes with the line

```
return pcoordinates
```

I think what you are meaning to do is print those details for debugging - in that case you can just change it to

```
print(pcoordinates)
```

and

```
print((x, y))
```

instead of the later `return` statement. That way the `print` command you already have will be reachable.

Comment: This definitely fixed my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: In that case you might like to upvote and/or accept this answer?

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."